# KAFKA - ERROR Failed to write meta.properties due to (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)

Tags: apache-kafka

I set up Kafka source code read environment on Windows10,
and encourted with error below, so what is wrong, I am a fresh man to learn kafka

```
[2021-04-29 19:57:42,957] ERROR Failed to write meta.properties due to (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
[2021-04-29 19:57:42,973] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
```

and another ERROR below

```
[2021-04-29 19:57:43,821] ERROR Error while writing to checkpoint file C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs\recovery-point-offset-checkpoint (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
[2021-04-29 19:57:43,823] ERROR Disk error while writing recovery offsets checkpoint in directory C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs: Error while writing to checkpoint file C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs\recovery-point-offset-checkpoint (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-04-29 19:57:43,833] ERROR Error while writing to checkpoint file C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs\log-start-offset-checkpoint (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
[2021-04-29 19:57:43,834] ERROR Disk error while writing log start offsets checkpoint in directory C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs: Error while writing to checkpoint file C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs\log-start-offset-checkpoint (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

Comment: The Error seems reasonable, can you check if you're able to write files to `C:\Users\a\workspace\kafka\logs`?

Answer (score 18):

I downgraded to the Kafka 2.8.1 version (https://dlcdn.apache.org/kafka/2.8.1) and after that everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common error when log retention happens. **Version does not matter**.

Kafka simply doesn't have good support for windows filesystem.

You can use WSL2 or Docker to work around these limitations - https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Answer (score 0):

Emebeded kafka work with Spring initializer (https://start.spring.io/) 2.5.9
with dependencies Spring for Apache Kafka and Spring Web